# Access connection string from (ARM Template) WebSite.json OR override Web.config with ARM Template Settings

Tags: json, connection-string, azure-resource-manager

I just started out with ARM Templates and I have a WebApp_ConnString in my WebSite.json.

Can I make the settings override the connection string in Web.config?

If not, and I need to remove the connection string in Web.config, how do I access the connection string in WebSite.json from my application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer;

All the ARM Templates do is override your local settings. So if in my webconfig, I have a connection string defined as follows;

```
connectionStrings>
    <add name="myConnectionString" connectionString="Server=localhost;Database=TimeTracker;uid=sa;pass=GodM0de1$;"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

Then inside my website.json, I would have the following;

```
  "properties": {
    "name": "[variables('webSiteName')]",
    "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]",
    "siteConfig": {
      "connectionStrings": [
        {
          "name": "myConnectionString",
          "connectionString": "[parameters('WebApp_ConnString')]",
          "type": 1 /* SQL  SERVER */
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Then insides my WebSite.enviornment.parameters.json file I would have the following;

```
"WebApp_ConnString": {
  "value": "Server=server01.corp.local;Database=TimeTracker;uid=sa;pass=IL0v3G0@tS3x;"
}
```